# Doesn't override function JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have HTML page contains two element: input text and save button. I need, that JQuery override onclick function. When user click button save, JQuery must call function Validate() and if field validate, call default function. So I need, that if textbox lenght not equalse 14 show message-> "The field not valid!". If yes, call default function, and I need see alert->"123". But now it's not work. So, how this is fixed?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="demo_form.asp">
    Phone: <input type="text" name="Phone" title="title1" value="(999) 999-9999">
    <input class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" type="button" target="_self" accesskey="O" 
    onclick="alert('123')" value="Save" >
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = $('input[value="Save"]').click;
    $('input[value="Save"]').click(Validate);

    function Validate() {
        if ($('input[title="title1"]').val().length != 14) {
            alert("The field not valid!");
        }else {
            temp();
        }
    }
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Sorry. I didn't say about html. This page generate on ASP.  The event "onclick="alert('123')"" Give me server, I can't use Id on form, button, because it's any time different. I can use only value and title, because server doesn't change it. I can't remove onclick. So that's why I need override onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I don't think there's any way for one handler to prevent another handler from running (you can only prevent the default action), and I'm not even sure the order of activation of the inline handler versus the ones added by jQuery is specified. So you need to remove the inline handler from the element, and call it explicitly from your validation function.

```
$(function() {
    var old_click_handler = $('input[value="Save"]').attr('onclick');
    $('input[value="Save"]').attr('onclick', null).click(Validate);

    function Validate() {
        if ($('input[title="title1"]').val().length != 14) {
            alert("The field not valid!");
        } else {
            if (typeof old_click_handler == 'string') {
                eval(old_click_handler);
            } else {
                old_click_handler();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think we both misunderstood the OP's question. In this instance, calling `preventDefault()` doesn't prevent the already-bound `onclick` attribute from firing **before** the custom alert > http://jsfiddle.net/Cea7z/1/. Notice how changing the field value first triggers an alert of `123`, and then the desired output? I believe the OP is asking how to prevent the initial function from triggering, if the `if()` statement is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you gave to "override" the event? Just add the validation *in* the event. Also, use `name` rather than `title` to identify elements.

```
<input type="text" name="Phone" title="title1" value="(999) 999-9999">
<input type="button" id="myButton" />

$("#myButton").click(function() {
    if(Validate())
        temp();
    else
        alert("The field not valid!");
});

function Validate() {
    if ($("input[name=Phone]").val().length != 14) {
        return false;
    return true;
}

function temp() {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a loop. Your clickhandler does some validation, but if the validation is OK, you basically call the validation again.

I suggest you use the form's `onsubmit` instead and use `return false` if the input doesn't validate (or use `event.stopPropagation()`).

```
<form id="myform">
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').submit(function (event) {
        var value = $('input[title="title1"]').val();
        if (value.length !== 14) {
            return false;
        }
     });
 });
```

Comment: No. I can't modify form and input different tag because it's asp server.

Comment: The ID was just to make it easier to identify the form. Use `$('form').first` or something similar, then.